# nginx change root folder for specific url

Tags: nginx, path, root

I have a configuration file like this one below:

```
    server {

        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset utf-8;
        root   html/laravel/public;
        index  index.html index.php;

        #browse folders if no index file
        autoindex on;

        # enforce NO www
        if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
        {
            set $host_without_www $1;
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
        }

        # serve static files directly
        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
            access_log off;
            #expires max;
        }

        # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
        if (!-d $request_filename)
        {
            rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
        }

        # canonicalize codeigniter url end points
        # if your default controller is something other than "welcome" you should change the following
        # if ($request_uri ~* ^(/lobby(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
        # {
        #     rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
        # }

        # removes trailing "index" from all controllers
        if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
        {
            rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
        }

        # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
            break;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location /backend/ {
            root /html/frontend;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }

        # catch all
        # error_page 404 /index.php;

        # location ~ \.php$ {
        # try_files $uri =404;
        #         fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php.socket;
        #         fastcgi_index index.php;
        #         #include fastcgi_params;
        #         include /home/tamer/code/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        # }
        # access_log /home/tamer/code/laravel/storage/logs.access.log;
        # error_log  /home/tamer/code/laravel/storage/logs.error.log;
    }
```

I have to change root folder to `html/backend` for any url with `$host/backend/`. All rules for load pages have to be the same, only root folder have to change.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8):

```
server {
  location / {
    root /data/www;
  }

  location /images/ {
    root /data;
    rewrite ^/images/(.+?)$ $1 break; #following is the explation
  }
}
```

- use **break** to continue; the root in location will take effect
- use **last** to internal simulate request; the root in location maybe will not take effect
- use **permanent** to 301 redirect;
- use **redirect** to 302 redirect;

Answer (score 1):

adding 127.0.0.1 to `server_name` to be able to use the link you provided in the comment `127.0.0.1`

```
server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
```

also you still need to have the `backend` location with `root` inside it.

```
location /backend/ {
    root /html/backend;
}
```

Comment: No it is not like that. It was just a test. It doesn't work. When i open http://127.0.0.1/backend/ still open root /html/laravel/public. This block doesn't change anything.

Comment: Does it work with http://localhost/backend ? , if it does you need to add 127.0.0.1 to the `server_name`, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a wild guess here:

```
location /backend/ {
    root /html/backend;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
}
```

This means: all requests to .../backend/* will be redirected to the location block of php followed after:

```
location ~ \.php${ ... }
```

and php will handle those requests as backend scripts

Answer (score 0):

Nginx [Beginner's Guide](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#static) has this example:

```
server {
  location / {
    root /data/www;
  }

  location /images/ {
    root /data;
  }
}
```

So in theory this should work for you:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location / {
    root html/laravel/public;
  }

  location /backend/ {
    root html/backend;
  }

  # common config goes here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly you can use [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) to change just the OS search path for a specific location:

> Defines a replacement for the specified location. For example, with the following configuration on request of “/i/top.gif”, the file /data/w3/images/top.gif will be sent.

```
location /i/ {
    alias /data/w3/images/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define new location and use alias instead of root or else the behaviour would be funky. Also you need to define location for .php to use $request_filename.

```
location /backend {
    alias /html/backend;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```